# How to make up a sed script file?

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have this two commands with sed, but I want to create a script (a .sed file) with these two commands...

I don't know how to create a sed script. Any help, please?

```
sed -E 's/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9])(;[^;]*;[^;]*)$/\1.\20\3/' \ -E 's/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9]{2})[0-9]+(;[^;]*;[^;]*)$/\1.\2\3/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the code to a file:

*script.sed*

```
s/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9])(;[^;]*;[^;]*)$/\1.\20\3/
s/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9]{2})[0-9]+(;[^;]*;[^;]*)$/\1.\2\3/
```

Run it with the correct parameteres:

```
sed -Ef script.sed
```

Or with shebang (`#!`):

*script2.sed*

```
#!/bin/sed -Ef

s/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9])(;[^;]*;[^;]*)$/\1.\20\3/
s/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9]{2})[0-9]+(;[^;]*;[^;]*)$/\1.\2\3/
```

Run it like this:

```
chmod u+x script2.sed
./script2.sed
```

Comment: Add a shebang `#!/bin/sed -Ef` and add executable permissions and then just `./script`